# How to resolve dependency issues in ivy with infinispan dependency?

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies, ivy, infinispan

I have problems resolving dependencies of an infinispan library (infinispan-jcache). If I run `ant ivy-retrieve` then I got following message:

```
ivy-retrieve:
[ivy:cleancache] :: Apache Ivy 2.5.0-rc1 - 20180412005306 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:cleancache] :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/andreas/.ant/lib/ivy-2.5.0-rc1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: example#ivy;working@ubuntu-dev
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 1473ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: org.infinispan#infinispan-jcache;9.4.8.Final: org.infinispan#infinispan-jcache-parent;9.4.8.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.8.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.8.Final
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
/home/andreas/git/ivy-test/build.xml:5: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 2 seconds
```

If I enable verbose output the problematic dependency seems to be `infinispan-build-configuration-parent-9.4.8.Final.jar` which simply doesn't exists in the central maven repo

```
[ivy:retrieve] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/infinispan/infinispan-build-configuration-parent/9.4.8.Final/infinispan-build-configuration-parent-9.4.8.Final.jar
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="ivy" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <target name="ivy-retrieve" description="retrieve dependencies locally">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="example" module="ivy"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.infinispan" name="infinispan-jcache" rev="9.4.8.Final" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Does anyone have a nice solution on how to download the infinispan version as ivy dependency? The referenced folder on maven central only has a pom-file in it. Do I maybe have to configure ivy or just use a different repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That jar doesn't exist because build-configuration has packaging `pom`. I have tried this locally and Ivy's dependency resolver erroneously throws a org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException because it fails to understand the hierarchy...

```
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-bom;9.4.13.Final {} with public (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-bom;9.4.13.Final {} with main (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final {} with public (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final {} with main (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-commons;9.4.13.Final {*=[*]} with public (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
[ivy:retrieve] problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.infinispan#infinispan-commons;9.4.13.Final {*=[*]} with main (org.apache.ivy.plugins.circular.CircularDependencyException: org.infinispan#infinispan-parent;9.4.13.Final->org.infinispan#infinispan-build-configuration-parent;9.4.13.Final)
```

This looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1588

If you use the latest ivy.jar built from master, it works: https://builds.apache.org/view/All/job/Ivy/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/artifact/jars/